# Python 3.5 : TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nosigint'

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.5 to do doctest. There is always an error:

```
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\doctest.py", line 357, in __init__
    pdb.Pdb.__init__(self, stdout=out, nosigint=True)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nosigint'
```

It seems that the error occurs in the doctest.py file, but not in my own code.

I hope to define a class which is similar to dict. My code is:

```
class Dict(dict):
    '''
    Simple dict but also support access as x.y style.

    >>> d1 = Dict()
    >>> d1['x'] = 100
    >>> d1.x
    100
    >>> d1.y = 200
    >>> d1['y']
    200
    >>> d2 = Dict(a=1, b=2, c='3')
    >>> d2.c
    '3'
    >>> d2['empty']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    KeyError: 'empty'
    >>> d2.empty
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    AttributeError: 'Dict' object has no attribute 'empty'
    '''
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Dict, self).__init__(**kw)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(r"'Dict' object has no attribute '%s'" % key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

if __name__=='__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Anaconda Python distribution.

Are you running using the Spyder IDE?

There is an [open bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1855) in Spyder's issue tracker.

The suggested work-around involves modifying the source of `pdb` and `doctest`.

> For a shoddy quick fix you can remove the
>
> `nosigint=True` argument from the `pdb.Pdb.init` in `doctest.py`
>
> and change the default value of `nosigint` to`True` in `pdb.py`

if you are being affected by this bug, you can encourage the folk who make Spyder to fix it by [Subscribing to Notifications about this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/9)

Comment: I am using Spyder IDE. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is another potential solution that I have used to work around this bug.  You can add an `__init__` method to the `SpyderPdb` class that sets a default value for the missing `nosigint` argument.

I'm using the WinPython distribution to get Spyder, but it's probably something similar for Anaconda.  For Python 3.5+ it's in: \WinPython...\python...\Lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py

For earlier versions it might be in ...\Lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py

```
class SpyderPdb(pdb.Pdb):
    def __init__(self, completekey='tab', stdin=None, stdout=None, skip=None, nosigint=False):
        super(pdb.Pdb, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder developer here*) This issue is going to be fixed in Spyder **3.1.4**, to be released in mid March/2017.